# Javascript capture form text field onChange to hidden field

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with a simple text field for a person's full name.

After a user enters their name and moves/tabs to the next field, I want to be able to capture the full name, extract only the first name, and attach to a separate hidden form field.

If the user goes back and corrects their full name, the extraction should repeat to get the correct first name.  The full name text field would still be passed along during form submittal.

I'm thinking plain JS would be the best approach (I'm not using JQuery).

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: *"...extract only the first name, and attach to a separate hidden form field"* Is there a reason for such behavior? Wouldn't 2 inputs for first and last names be a better UX?

Comment: I try to keep inputs as few as possible because of mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

this is your html

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="fullname" value="" id="fullname">
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="" id="firstname">
</form>
```

this is your javascript

```
<script>

    let fullName = document.getElementById("fullname");

    let firstName = document.getElementById("firstname");

    fullName.addEventListener("blur", function() {

      let names = fullName.value.split(" ");

      if (names.length > 0) {
        firstName.value = names[0];
      }

    });

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3k8kur9u/

Comment: Didn't think to use the addEventListener!  Works great.  Thanks!